# CS:GO Demo Transfer from Server to Website

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there anyway I could automated transfer CS:GO demos from GOTV on community server to an web server?
Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Write a little copy tool that keeps an eye on the demo folder

Comment: yes.. a little batch which is looking on the ftp and transfering it could work

Comment: Shouldn't be questions on batch files or automation be asked on [su]  or [so]?

Comment: @aytimothy there's not enough information in this post for it to be asked on one of those suggested sites. It'd be closed and downvoted if it was asked in this form.